# Input warnings failing to correctly conditionally render with JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let emailErr = false; somewhere above


<div className="inputDiv">
              <label htmlFor="email"> Email </label>
              <div className="input flex">
                <MdMarkEmailRead className="icon" />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Enter Email"
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    setEmail(event.target.value);
                  }}
                  onInput={() => {
                    verifyAll();
                  }}
                  onBlur={() => {
                    verifyEmail(email);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            **{emailErr && <span className="text-danger"> Please enter a valid email. </span>}**

const verifyEmail = (email) => {
    const pattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if(pattern.test(email)) {
      return true;
    }
    emailErr = true;
  }

const verifyAll = () => {
  if (verifyEmail(email) && verifySecure(password) && verifyPasswords()) {
    setDisabled(false);
  }
  else setDisabled(true);
}
```

Here are the relevant code snippets. The span ends up not rendering ever, but there are no errors.

I tried setting the condition to directly call verifyEmail() and it worked that way, but then it would constantly be showing the error message until an input was valid. I tried setting an "if null, don't call this" condition but it seemed to be ignored. I'm not committed to the way I'm doing this and I would appreciate any kind of assistance. The one thing I do want to keep is the button being disabled when all inputs are not valid.

Comment: you have to use `useState` with `emailErr`, declare variable using `let` or `const` won't trigger re-render in React.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better.
Based on your code when you input something the component will rerender

```js
onChange={(event) => {
     setEmail(event.target.value);
}}
```

and you just need to verify it directly (don't need to set a new state)

```js
const isValidEmail = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email);
const isSecurePassword = ....
const isValidPassword = ...

{!isValidEmail && <span className="text-danger"> Please enter a valid email. </span>}
```